# How to self join a table and present a limited number of results, based on a passed criteria, in one row

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a jobs booked report that will show all jobs created for a specific date, followed by the last three jobs for each item#, i-no, on those jobs and display the data in the same row as the job from the specific date.  If no previous jobs, the fields would be null (currently #NUM! because we're doing it manually in Excel).  If only one previous job, the pertinent fields would be populated and the rest null, and so on..
I have a job table and jobheader table.  They both contain very similar pieces of data, with the exception of two things, the job table contains a created-date and no item# field while the jobheader table contains the item# but no created-date field.  (I'm working to get the jobheader table all-inclusive, but have to find a solution to this report regardless.)
Here are my tables:

```
show CREATE TABLE job

job CREATE TABLE `job` (
`job-no` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
`job-no2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`std-fix-cost` double DEFAULT NULL,
`std-lab-cost` double DEFAULT NULL,
`std-mat-cost` double DEFAULT NULL,
`std-tot-cost` double DEFAULT NULL,
`std-var-cost` double DEFAULT NULL,
`create-date` date DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8    


show CREATE TABLE jobheader 

jobheader   CREATE TABLE `jobheader` (
`sdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
`qty` double DEFAULT NULL,
`std-tot-cost` double DEFAULT NULL,
`std-mat-cost` double DEFAULT NULL,
`std-lab-cost` double DEFAULT NULL,
`std-fix-cost` double DEFAULT NULL,
`std-var-cost` double DEFAULT NULL,
`i-no` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
`job-no2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`job-no` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

These tables are joined by job-no and job-no2.

Here is the data from my tables:

```
job table:  
║ job-no   ║ job-no2 ║ std-fix-cost   ║ std-lab-cost ║ std-mat-cost ║ std-tot-cost ║ std-var-cost ║ create-date ║
║ 786993 ║ 0           ║ 177.2188     ║ 515.1117      ║ 1283.929     ║ 2346.3662   ║ 370.1067   ║ 4/04/2019 ║
║ 787041 ║ 0           ║ 59.5367       ║ 70.8075       ║ 886.2611     ║ 1065.5539   ║ 48.9486     ║ 4/04/2019 ║
║ 787041 ║ 1           ║ 103.475       ║ 123.0637      ║ 1067.8726   ║ 1379.4843   ║ 85.073     ║ 4/04/2019 ║  

jobheader table:  
║sdate║qty║std-tot-cost ║std-mat-cost║std-lab-cost║std-fix-cost║std-var-cost║i-no        ║j2║job-no║  
║NULL ║200║    1297.6372║    942.9434║    140.078 ║    117.781 ║    96.8348 ║NEOIN77886NX║1 ║734701║  
║NULL ║250║    1230.327 ║    918.7153║    123.0637║    103.475 ║    85.073  ║NEOIN77886NX║3 ║762822║  
║NULL ║200║    2346.3662║    1283.929║    515.1117║    177.2188║    370.1067║MEDV25653   ║0 ║786993║  
║NULL ║500║    1065.5539║    886.2611║    70.8075 ║    59.5367 ║    48.9486 ║NEOIN77886NX║0 ║787041║
```

Expected output (this is going to be messy because it's a lot of data).  I've also attached an image for a better representation of what I'm looking for.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTnrM.png):

```
║job-no║j2║create-date║i-no        ║qty║sdate║std-tot-cost║std-mat-cost║std-lab-cost║std-fix-cost║std-var-cost║job-no║j2║Qty║std-tot-cost║std-mat-cost║std-lab-cost║std-fix-cost║std-var-cost║job-no║j2║Qty║std-tot-cost ║std-mat-cost║std-lab-cost║std-fix-cost║std-var-cost║job-no║j2   ║Qty  ║std-tot-cost║std-mat-cost║std-lab-cost║std-fix-cost║std-var-cost║  
║787041║0 ║4/4/2019   ║NEOIN77886NX║200║     ║    1,349.54║    994.85  ║   
 140.08  ║     117.78 ║96.83   ║762822║3 ║250║ 
   1230.327║    918.7153║    123.0637║    103.475 ║    85.073  ║734701║1 ║200║ 
   1297.6372║    942.9434║    140.078 ║    117.781 ║    96.8348 ║#NUM! ║#NUM!║#NUM!║#NUM!   ║#NUM!   ║#NUM!   ║#NUM!   ║#NUM!   ║  
║786993║0 ║4/4/2019   ║MEDV25653   ║200║     ║    2,346.37║    1,283.93║   
 515.11  ║    177.22  ║    370.11  ║#NUM! ║#NUM!║#NUM!║#NUM!║#NUM!║#NUM!║#NUM!║#NUM!║#NUM!║#NUM!║#NUM! ║#NUM!║#NUM!║#NUM!║#NUM!║#NUM!║#NUM!║#NUM!║#NUM!║#NUM!║#NUM!║#NUM!║#NUM!║#NUM!║
```

Below is my query.  Eliminating the calculated fields for now, it runs without error, just gives me too many results for each of the jobs created yesterday.  I wrote these as subqueries so that I could limit the number of results, but I can't seem to figure out how to pass the jobh.i-no into the subqueries, thus not allowing me to limit the results.  If I can figure that out, and use LIMIT1, LIMIT1,1, and LIMIT 2,1 for each of my subqueries, I think this will produce what I'm looking for.  Any suggestions on how to change my query or how to pass on the Item# to the subqueries?

```
select

job.`job-no`,

job.`job-no2`,

job.`create-date`,

jobh.`i-no`,

jobh.qty,

jobh.`start-date`,

jobh.`std-tot-cost`,

jobh.`std-mat-cost`,

jobh.`std-lab-cost`,

jobh.`std-fix-cost`,

jobh.`std-var-cost`,

tmp.`std-tot-cost` as PreviousJobStdTotCost,

tmp.`std-mat-cost` as PreviousJobStdMatCost,

tmp.`std-lab-cost` as PreviousJobStdLabCost,

tmp.`std-fix-cost` as PreviousJobStdFixCost,

tmp.`std-var-cost` as PreviousJobStdVarCost,

tmp2.`std-tot-cost` as PreviousJob2StdTotCost,

tmp2.`std-mat-cost` as PreviousJob2StdMaCost,

tmp2.`std-lab-cost` as PreviousJob2StdLabCost,

tmp2.`std-fix-cost` as PreviousJob2StdFixCost,

tmp2.`std-var-cost` as PreviousJob2StdVarCost,

tmp3.`std-tot-cost` as PreviousJob3StdTotCost,

tmp3.`std-mat-cost` as PreviousJob3StdMatCost,

tmp3.`std-lab-cost` as PreviousJob3StdLabCost,

tmp3.`std-fix-cost` as PreviousJob3StdFixCost,

tmp3.`std-var-cost` as PreviousJob3StdVarCost

from asi.job as job

left join asi.jobheader  as jobh on job.`job-no`=jobh.`job-no` and job.`job-no2`=jobh.`job-no2`

left join (select jobh1.`i-no`, jobh1.`job-no`, jobh1.`std-tot-cost`, jobh1.`std-mat-cost`, jobh1.`std-lab-cost`, jobh1.`std-fix-cost`, jobh1.`std-var-cost` from asi.jobheader as jobh1 order by jobh1.`job-no` desc) tmp on tmp.`i-no`=jobh.`i-no` and tmp.`job-no`not equal to jobh.`job-no`

left join (select jobh2.`i-no`, jobh2.`job-no`, jobh2.`std-tot-cost`, jobh2.`std-mat-cost`, jobh2.`std-lab-cost`, jobh2.`std-fix-cost`, jobh2.`std-var-cost` from asi.jobheader as jobh2 order by jobh2.`job-no` desc ) tmp2 on tmp2.`i-no`=tmp.`i-no` and tmp2.`job-no` not equal to tmp.`job-no`

left join (select jobh3.`i-no`, jobh3.`job-no`, jobh3.`std-tot-cost`, jobh3.`std-mat-cost`, jobh3.`std-lab-cost`, jobh3.`std-fix-cost`, jobh3.`std-var-cost` from asi.jobheader as jobh3 order by jobh3.`job-no` desc) tmp3 on tmp3.`i-no`=tmp2.`i-no` and tmp3.`job-no` not equal to tmp2.`job-no`

where asi.job.`create-date`="2019-04-04" and asi.job.`job-no` is not null and asi.job.`job-no`""
```

Comment: Those don't need to be subqueries; I could maybe suggest more, but it looks like something mangled your join conditions

Comment: I'm not sure why it's doing that.  The last part of the joins have "not equal" signs, <>, and they are there when I go to edit my post, but not showing up in the thread.

Comment: I've added "not equal to" text just for some clarity.

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think this might work, but I am not positive; and I definitely doubt it will perform fast, but it's something....

```
select
job.`job-no`,
job.`job-no2`,
job.`create-date`,
jobh.`i-no`,
jobh.qty,
jobh.`start-date`,
jobh.`std-tot-cost`, jobh.`std-mat-cost`, jobh.`std-lab-cost`, jobh.`std-fix-cost`, jobh.`std-var-cost`,
tmp.`std-tot-cost` as PreviousJobStdTotCost, tmp.`std-mat-cost` as PreviousJobStdMatCost, tmp.`std-lab-cost` as PreviousJobStdLabCost, tmp.`std-fix-cost` as PreviousJobStdFixCost, tmp.`std-var-cost` as PreviousJobStdVarCost,
tmp2.`std-tot-cost` as PreviousJob2StdTotCost, tmp2.`std-mat-cost` as PreviousJob2StdMaCost, tmp2.`std-lab-cost` as PreviousJob2StdLabCost, tmp2.`std-fix-cost` as PreviousJob2StdFixCost, tmp2.`std-var-cost` as PreviousJob2StdVarCost,
tmp3.`std-tot-cost` as PreviousJob3StdTotCost, tmp3.`std-mat-cost` as PreviousJob3StdMatCost, tmp3.`std-lab-cost` as PreviousJob3StdLabCost,
tmp3.`std-fix-cost` as PreviousJob3StdFixCost, tmp3.`std-var-cost` as PreviousJob3StdVarCost
from asi.job as job
left join asi.jobheader as jobh on job.`job-no`=jobh.`job-no` and job.`job-no2`=jobh.`job-no2`
left join (
    select jobh1.`std-tot-cost`, jobh1.`std-mat-cost`, jobh1.`std-lab-cost`, jobh1.`std-fix-cost`, jobh1.`std-var-cost` 
    from asi.jobheader as jobh1 
    where jobh1.`i-no`=jobh.`i-no` and jobh1.`job-no` < jobh.`job-no`
    order by jobh1.`job-no` desc
    limit 1
) tmp on 1=1
left join (
    select jobh2.`std-tot-cost`, jobh2.`std-mat-cost`, jobh2.`std-lab-cost`, jobh2.`std-fix-cost`, jobh2.`std-var-cost` 
    from asi.jobheader as jobh2 
    where jobh2.`i-no`=tmp.`i-no` and jobh2.`job-no` < tmp.`job-no`
    order by jobh2.`job-no` desc 
    limit 1
) tmp2 on 1=1
left join (
    select jobh3.`std-tot-cost`, jobh3.`std-mat-cost`, jobh3.`std-lab-cost`, jobh3.`std-fix-cost`, jobh3.`std-var-cost` 
    from asi.jobheader as jobh3 
    where jobh3.`i-no`=tmp2.`i-no` and jobh3.`job-no` < tmp2.`job-no`
    order by jobh3.`job-no` desc
    limit 1
) tmp3 on 1=1
where asi.job.`create-date`="2019-04-04" 
    and asi.job.`job-no` is not null 
    and asi.job.`job-no`
```

but, if you can do some processing on the end receiving the data, this might be a better solution:

```
select
job.`job-no`,
job.`job-no2`,
job.`create-date`,
jobh.`i-no`,
jobh.qty,
jobh.`start-date`, jobh.`std-tot-cost`, jobh.`std-mat-cost`, jobh.`std-lab-cost`, jobh.`std-fix-cost`, jobh.`std-var-cost`,
prev.`start-date` AS PreviousJobStartDate, prev.`std-tot-cost` as PreviousJobStdTotCost, prev.`std-mat-cost` as PreviousJobStdMatCost, prev.`std-lab-cost` as PreviousJobStdLabCost, prev.`std-fix-cost` as PreviousJobStdFixCost, prev.`std-var-cost` as PreviousJobStdVarCost
from asi.job as job
left join asi.jobheader as jobh on job.`job-no`=jobh.`job-no` and job.`job-no2`=jobh.`job-no2`
left join (
    select jobh1.`start-date`, jobh1.`std-tot-cost`, jobh1.`std-mat-cost`, jobh1.`std-lab-cost`, jobh1.`std-fix-cost`, jobh1.`std-var-cost` 
    from asi.jobheader as jobh1 
    where jobh1.`i-no`=jobh.`i-no` and jobh1.`job-no` < jobh.`job-no`
    order by jobh1.`job-no` desc
    limit 3
) prev on 1=1
where asi.job.`create-date`="2019-04-04" 
    and asi.job.`job-no` is not null 
    and asi.job.`job-no`
```

Comment: mysql 5.5  I tried the query above, but I get a mysql error, #1054 - Unknown column 'jobh.i-no' in 'where clause'.  It seems I can't pass a field into the subquery.  Sorry, my comment is for your first query.  I didn't even notice the second query until now.  I'll try that now and let you know.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hmm, I didn't double check every bit of the cut-paste I started with from the question; but that should not be the error you get with the queries I provided, they should give you errors based on that final where condition being incomplete. I am guessing whatever you added there to complete it is causing the issue. What did you add or change? Why would it need to reference `jobh1`?

Comment: I added <>" " to the end of the final where clause.  The error is originating from the subqueries.  I can take the where clauses out of the subqueries and get no errors.

Comment: Are you sure the field names are right? I just tried setting up a test on a "fiddle" site and noticed you field names do not agree from one section of your question to the next.

Comment: I have corrected the field names on the SHOW CREATE tables and the table data in my original question.  The query was already using the correct names.  I apologize for this.  Very new to posting questions and thought I was helping for readability purposes.  Lesson learned.

Comment: Yeah, looks like it doesn't work in dbfiddle either. Sorry. I could have sworn correlated subqueries could be used in left joins; but I generally avoid them unless they are actually needed so my familiarity with them is limited.